# How to add the form in accordion.

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am New in angular, when user click on accordion header then accordion body display the form.rather than showing the html code in the body.I am adding form tag is it correct way which i following if other please let me know.thanks in advance.

```
<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="oneAtATime">
    Open only one at a time
</label>

<accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
<accordion-group heading="Static Header">
      This content is straight in the temmplate.
</accordion-group>
<accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
      {{group.template}}
</accordion-group>
<accordion-group heading="Dynamic Body Content">
<p>The body of the accordion group grows to fit the contents</p>
<button class="btn btn-small" ng-click="addItem()">Add Item</button>
<div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>
</accordion-group>
</accordion>
</div>
</body>
<script>
angular.module('pl', ['ui.bootstrap']);
function AccordionDemoCtrl($scope) {
$scope.oneAtATime = true;

$scope.groups = [
{
title: "Member application",
template: '<form><input type="text"></form>'
},
{
title: "Contact us",
template:'<form> <input type="text"><input type="password"> </form>'   
}
];

$scope.items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];

$scope.addItem = function() {
var newItemNo = $scope.items.length + 1;
$scope.items.push('Item ' + newItemNo);
};
}

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: you've called your function a controller but its not, its weird. If you intend this to be a controller then you should not manipulate the DOM with it. adding forms in a scope like this is wrong, what's wrong with adding them in your html?

Comment: If you would Like to see how to build an angular app with separation of concerns check out my github repo [DoingAngularRight](https://github.com/joeLloyd/DoingAngularRight)